# Next Row Matching Criteria - python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of roughly 6 million rows, which I need to repeatedly analyse for simulations. The following is a very simple representation of the data.

For rows where `action=1`,

I am tying to devise an efficient way to do this

`For index,row in df.iterrows():`

```
`Result = the first next row where (price2 is >= row.price1 +4) and index > row.index`
```

or if that doesn't exist

`return index+100` (i.e the activity times out).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Action(y/n)' : [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0], 'Price1' : [1,8,3,1,7,3,8,2,3,1], 'Price2' : [2,1,1,5,3,1,2,11,12,1]})
print(df)

        Action(y/n)  Price1  Price2
0            0       1       2
1            1       8       1
2            0       3       1
3            0       1       5
4            1       7       3
5            0       3       1
6            1       8       2
7            0       2      11
8            0       3      12
9            0       1       1
```

Resulting in something like this:

```
       Action(y/n)  Price1  Price2  ExitRow(IndexOfRowWhereCriteriaMet)
0            0       14      2     9
1            1       8       1     8
2            0       3       1     102
3            0       1       5     103
4            1       7       3     7
5            0       3       1     105
6            1       8       2     8
7            0       2      11     107
8            0       3      12     108
9            0       1       1     109
```

I have tried a few methods,which are all really slow. 
This best one maps it, but really not fast enough.

```
df['ExitRow'] = list(map(ATestFcn, df.index,df.price1))

def ATestFcn(dfIx, dfPrice1):
    ExitRow = df[((df.price2>(price1+4))&(df.index >dfIx)&    (df.index<=dfIx+TimeOut))].index.min()
    if pd.isnull(ExitRow):
        return dfIx+ TimeOut
    else:
        return ExitRow
```

I also tested this with a loop, it was about 25% slower - but it was ideas-wise
essentially the same.

I'm thinking there must be a smarter or faster way to do this, a mask could have been useful except you can't fill down with this data as `price2` for one row might be thousands of rows after the `price2` for another row, and I can't find a way to turn a merge into a cross apply like one might in TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

To find the index of the first row which meet your criterion, you could use

```
    cur_row_idx = 100 # we want the row after 100
    next_row_idx = (df[cur_row_idx:].Price2 >= df[cur_row_idx:].Price1 + 4).argmax()
```

Then, you want to set a cutoff, say, the max value you getting is the `TimeOut` - so it could be

```
    next_row_idx = np.min(((df[cur_row_idx:].Price2 >= df[cur_row_idx:].Price1 + 4).argmax() , dfIx + TimeOut))
```

I did not check the performance on the large datasets, but hope it helps. 
If you wish, you also can wrap it into a function:

```
    def ATestFcn(dfIx, df, TimeOut):
        return np.min(((df[dfIx:].Price2 >= df[dfIx:].Price1 + 4).argmax() , dfIx + TimeOut))
```

**Edit:** Just tested it, it is quite fast, see the results below:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    Price1 = np.random.randint(100, size=10e6)
    Price2 = np.random.randint(100, size=10e6)

    df["Price1"] = Price1
    df["Price2"] = Price2

    timeit ATestFcn(np.random.randint(1e6), df, 100)

    Out[62]: 1 loops, best of 3: 289 ms per loop
```

Comment: I've amended my description of the issue as when I was investigating your answer I realised the description was vague/wrong. So your answer although good isn't answering the question I intended to ask.

Comment: This is how I amended your ideas:

`import datetime

TimeOut = 100 
def ATestFcn(dfIx,PriceA):
    return np.min(((   (df[dfIx:].Price2 >= PriceA + 4) & (df[dfIx:].index > dfIx)   ).argmax() , dfIx + TimeOut))


# Test1


xx = (datetime.datetime.now())

df['Exit'] = list(map(ATestFcn, df.index, df.Price1))

yy = (datetime.datetime.now())

print(yy-xx)`